# Is it possible to define a maximum step size (Euclidean distance) for fmincon's interior-point method in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, constraints

I am interested in limiting the maximum step that fmincon's interior-point method can take from its current point. More specifically, I would like to ensure that the method cannot move farther than a given Euclidean distance at every step. The method may go farther than that in the end, but no in a single step. So, in other words, assuming a maximum Euclidean distance of 1.0, the local optimizer could go from x0 = 3 to x = 6, but it would need 3 movements at least. Is it possible to natively achieve this with one of its options and I am not aware of that?

What I have tried so far is to define this aspect as an external non-linear constraint. By doing so, I would need to detect that the method stopped at the border and then restart it there (which resets the maximum Euclidean distance). However, I got strange results as described in [this question about misconvergence depending on the constraint](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/513188-convergence-problems-of-fmincon-interior-point-with-a-nonlinear-constraint).

To summarize the problem of the approach linked, if you try to minimize f(x) = x^2 starting at -0.4 (for instance) with the referred constraint of 1.0 as the maximum Euclidean distance, fmincon will not move. However, it would without that constraint (which, in fact, should not affect since -0.4 is nearer that 1.0 to the global minimum of the function, i.e., 0). This is some sample code with and without the non-linear constraint. Without:

```
[x, fval] = fmincon(@(x) x^2, -0.4,[],[],[],[], -10, 10);
```

The result is: x = 1.5231e-11 with fval (objective function's value) = 2.3199e-22.

But, if we add the referred constraint of not reaching farther than 1.0 from the start (in Euclidean distance):

```
[x, fval] = fmincon(@(x) x^2, -0.4,[],[],[],[], -10, 10, @(x) NLConstraint(x, -0.4, 1.0));
```

Provided that:

```
function [c, ceq] = NLConstraint(x, x0, radius)
    c = norm(x-x0) - radius;
    ceq=[];
end
```

We get x = -0.4000 and fval = 0.1600, so fmincon does not move in the end even though the optimum is reachable within the given radius. To make it stranger, it successfully moves from -4 to -3 for example (so the constraint seems effective to me). It even moves if you start at -0.7.

Therefore, as introduced, I would be very grateful to anyone who knows how to define a maximum Euclidean distance from the current step to the next through the fmincon's interior-point options (or well, an explanation of what I see with the external non-linear constraint summarized and described in [1](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/513188-convergence-problems-of-fmincon-interior-point-with-a-nonlinear-constraint)).

Comment: A few thoughts/questions: (a) why do you want to do this in the first place? There may be a more elegant solution. (b) You can probably at least control some scaling of your step size through `HessianMultiplyFcn` or some of the other options--though these won't set an absolute maximum on step size.

Comment: Constraints will only affect the current estimate of `x` not the difference to the previous estimate. What you are looking for is to limit the **trust-region-radius** but I know only of that you can do this for the initial step with the option *InitTrustRegionRadius*.

Comment: @tmcg0 is right. You shouldn't need to do this as this is essentially what the algorithm does: determine the length (your radius) and the direction of the next step...

Comment: @ tmcg0, I am trying to implement a multi-modal optimizer, i.e., that tries to identify and keep track of different optima. According to its specification for any local optimizer coupled with it: "This means that the largest step made by the optimizer (...) is no larger than the radius (...). If the value of a new solution is better than that of the old center, the new solution becomes the center and the window is moved." (from Jelasity et al., "UEGO, an Abstract Clustering Technique for Multimodal Global Optimization", Journal of Heuristics, 7, 215-233, 2001).

Comment: @ChesterLC I see. Thank you for linking the paper. Truthfully, I'm not sure if MATLAB's built-in `fmincon` is the right tool for this job, given the amount of control you need to have on the optimizer. If you want to implement this approach literally, I would recommend starting with an existing codebase for interior point methods and work from there.
Alternatively, if you don't need to _literally_ implement this paper, but just want the philosophy of it, perhaps consider a different optimization method which gives you more control over step size. I think `lsqnonlin` has controls over lambda.

Comment: @tmcg0 Thank you for your interest. In the end, as you suggest, I have ignored the aspect of the maximum step size. In fact, since the species can move through the search space, I think that I can relax that aspect considering that "interior-point" is not stochastic and "should know what to do". Besides, the "fuse" stage of the method should deal with multiple convergences to the same result. Regards and thank you!